# How to use key generated by firebase database push method in write operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I am using react, redux and along with firebase. I have my action like below:

```
export function addPost(postData) {
    firebase.database().ref('posts').push().update({
        title: postData.title,
        text: postData.text,
        userId: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
        postid: ?????????
    })
    return {type: "ADD_POST", payload: postData}
}
```

I am suppose to create in firebase database something like this:

```
LY7iT1sgmJvjCmBh1GZ: {
    title: some title,
    text: some text,
    postid: LY7iT1sgmJvjCmBh1GZ
}
```

LY7iT1sgmJvjCmBh1GZ is unique key generated by push method. I want to my postId property be the same - how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) returns a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) whose [`key`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key) property is the randomly generated key on the client:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('posts').push();
const key = ref.key;
```

Then you can use that in your data:

```
ref.set({
    ...
    postid: key
});
```

Comment: Here is a link to the docs that explain how to get the unique key generated by push: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push

Comment: @jkerr838 Are you sure the OP is working with the Admin SDK here and not the client SDK?

Comment: Not sure, I guess it could be the Node.js SDK or the Javascript Client. Hard to tell since Javascript is everywhere now 

Comment: @jkerr838 If it was node, I'd expect access through an object traditionally called `admin`.  On the client side, you get an object called `firebase`, which is what we see here.  Mostly I'm hesitant to send someone to docs that are potentially confusing.